# How to add views to Show In menu for particular file types

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I use an older plugin called [Veloeclipse](http://code.google.com/p/veloeclipse/issues/list) for editing Velocity templates in Eclipse. There's been no development on this since 2009, which isn't a problem because it's mainly just for syntax highlighting and format validation. The really annoying thing about it, however, is that when I try to do **Show In** to view the current Velocity template within my Package Explorer or Project Explorer, the only available option is Properties. That's not really useful. I really need to be able to get to the file in one of the regular explorer views.

So I have sort of two questions:

- Is there a way to configure this without having to monkey with any code? A configuration file or something? I've grepped through my Eclipse installation and haven't seen anything, but I'm hoping that there's something I'm missing.
- So assuming that the answer to my first question is no, how do I go about modifying the plugin code so that it will show more than the Properties view in the Show In menu? Most of what I found on the plugin development wiki comes from the other direction: how to make your view or perspective appear in the Show In menu.

Any help with this would be hugely appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the plugin source code. it might do something different than other editors. What I mean is that the `show in` menu item that you have there is not the usual extension point but a hard coded context menu option.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I've gone through the code and looked for anything that would do the sort of thing to which you're referring and can't find anything obvious. E.g. I looked for "right", "click", "context", "menu", "show in", "properties", etc. There are a number of instances of many of those, of course, but that's just because those are very common development terms! I guess I'll try to create a plugin project around the code and see if I can debug it...